# @Value in spring boot is not injecting value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using EasyRules API in my code. Following is a rule class which accesses a double value from `application.properties` file present in `src/main/resources`:

```
@Rule(name = "Over-weight rule") // to indicate that this class is a rule
@PropertySource("/application.properties")
public class OverweightRule {

    /**
     * The user input which represents the data
     * that the rule will operate on.
    */
    private Metric metric;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("alertServiceDao")
    private AlertService alertService;

    @Value("${base.weight}")
    private double baseWeight;

    public OverweightRule(Metric metric) {
        this.metric = metric;
    }

    @Condition
    public boolean isOverweight() {
        // The rule should be applied only if the
        // weight in metric object shoots 10% over the base weight.
        if(metric.getWeight() > (baseWeight + (0.1 * baseWeight))) return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Action
    public void createAndStoreOverweightAlert() {
        // When rule conditions are satisfied,
        // an alert is created.
        Alert alert = new Alert();
        alert.setAlertType(Alert.AlertType.OVER_WEIGHT);
        alert.setWeight(metric.getWeight());
        alert.setTimeStamp(metric.getTimeStamp());
        alertService.createAlert(alert);
    }
}
```

The value in baseWeight is always 0.0 whereas I have set it to 150.0 in properties file. I read that Spring boot automatically reads values from `application.properties` file present in `src/main/resources` so no need to use `@PropertySource("/path to properties file")`. Still I added `@PropertySource` annotation but the result was same. What is wrong in this code? I do not want to add `@Configuration` to this class because I want to keep this class as a Rule class defined by easy rules framework.

Comment: When i had this problem before, it was because I was missing the getter and setter methods for that property in my class.

Comment: I tried adding getter and setter for baseWeight field but it was still 0.0

Comment: Make sure your src/main/resources is marked as a resource directory in your project. If its not then the properties file wont be present in the classpath when the application loads. If your using Maven then checkout https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: Yes I am using Maven. I added the <resources> tag in pom.xml to include all .properties files. And it is still not getting the value from application.properties. BTW, I thought Maven by default  looks for your project's resources under src/main/resources.

Comment: A rule isn't managed by Spring and as such will not receive the values. For Spring this class doesn't exists. If you want it to be injected make it a Spring managed bean and properly integrate Spring with the rule engine (or manually inject the rules into the the rules container.

Comment: Ah, I got your point. Thanks a lot ! I will annotate it with @Component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to declare as a `@Component` and removes the `@PropertySource` and keep the `@Value("${base.weight}")`

```
@Rule(name = "Over-weight rule") // to indicate that this class is a rule
@Component("myOverWeightRule")
public class OverweightRule {
```

When you create the `rulesEngineFactoryBean` you can autowire the `myOverWeightRule`:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
RulesEngineFactoryBean rulesEngineFactoryBean(OverweightRule myOverweightRule){
    RulesEngineFactoryBean rules = new RulesEngineFactoryBean();
    rules.setRules(Arrays.asList(myOverweightRule));
    return rules;
}
```

And finally call the fireRules getting the `rulesEngineFactoryBean`

```
        RulesEngine rulesEngine
                = (RulesEngine) ctx.getBean("rulesEngineFactoryBean");
        rulesEngine.fireRules();
```